# How to count pageX, pageY for divs with same classes separately from each other

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make hover effect like here: https://andstudio.lt/work/
So when user hover on title of project there is image appear which pinned to cursor.
I found some code in internet and created in codepen, here https://codepen.io/ChicagoJostik/pen/abzqXOv
It's actually working, but not properly.

First of all, I got problem here:

```
function moveCircle(e) {
  TweenMax.to(".cursor", 0.5, {
    css: {
      left: e.pageX,
      top: e.pageY
    },
  });
}
```

So when I hover on any project all "cursor's" pageX and pageY will be count.
How can I make count only for that "cursor" in which project I hovered?
I don't know maybe it's the problem that makes code working not properly,
but if you have any advice, you can write courageously.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example to play around with.

**Snippet:**

```js
$(".hoverme a").mouseenter(function() {
  img = $(this).attr("data-image");
  $(".image-placeholder").attr("style","background:url(" + img + ") no-repeat center center");
  $(".image-placeholder").addClass("close");

  $(document).on("mousemove", function(e) {
    $(".image-placeholder").css({
      left: e.pageX,
      top: e.pageY
    });
  });
});
$(".hoverme").mouseleave(function() {
  $(".image-placeholder").removeClass("close");
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #8f8d8d;
}

.container {
  padding: 75px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.hoverme {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.hoverme a {
  opacity: 0.5;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.hoverme a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.image-placeholder {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 30%;
  padding-bottom: 21%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.7);
  z-index: 9;
  background-size: cover !important;
  transition: opacity 0.1s, visibility 0.1s, transform 0.2s;
  left: -100%;
  top: -100%;
}

.image-placeholder.close {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="image-placeholder"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="hoverme">
    <a data-image="https://i.imgur.com/kuqQfXB.jpg">
      1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</a>
  </div>
  <div class="hoverme">
    <a data-image="https://i.imgur.com/UVP46pV.jpg">
      2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</a>
  </div>
  <div class="hoverme">
    <a data-image="https://i.imgur.com/8YLDZ4B.jpg">
      3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing eli</a>
  </div>
  <div class="hoverme">
    <a data-image="https://i.imgur.com/9uAL5Oh.jpg">
      4. Donec et velit volutpat, posuere orci pulvinar lobortis</a>
  </div>
</div>
```